# SQL Server - current user name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Which one should I use to record update made by users?

1. `SYSTEM_USER`, or
2. `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()`, or
3. `SUSER_SNAME()`

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`SYSTEM_USER` returns the current executing context, so this can return an impersonated context

`ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` returns the identity of the user that initially connected to the instance, so regardless whether the context is impersonated or not it will yield the original user that logged in, good for auditing.

`SUSER_SNAME()` this is used if you want to get the username by SID so `SUSER_SNAME` can be invoked with a parameter like such `SUSER_SNAME([server_user_sid])` but the SID is optional if you don’t pass that parameter the  current user is returned.

Comment: Can SUSER_SNAME() return an impersonated context?

Answer (score 0):

The current user (including during impersonation) can be found with `SELECT USER_NAME()`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/user-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16