# Table history trigger in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I'd like to create a trigger that writes to a history table with inserted values and before and after update values.  I would also like to include as much information about the account doing the update as is possible.  How would i include the account information in my trigger?

Here is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [update_history] ON MyTable
FOR UPDATE
AS
INSERT MyTable_History (id, BudgetNumber, PositionNumber, ModifiedDate, action, userId)
SELECT id, BudgetNumber, PositionNumber, GETDATE(), 'BEFORE UPDATE', '???'
FROM deleted

INSERT MyTable_History (id, BudgetNumber, PositionNumber, ModifiedDate, action, userId)
SELECT id, BudgetNumber, PositionNumber, GETDATE(), 'AFTER UPDATE', '???'
FROM inserted
```

What do i put in place of the '???'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If each user has an account, you can use the `SYSTEM_USER` function to determine the current user. However, if all your connections go through a proxy account, as is typical in most web site setups, then you have to rely on the proper userId being passed to the Update statement:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [update_history] ON MyTable
FOR UPDATE
AS
INSERT MyTable_History (id, BudgetNumber, PositionNumber, ModifiedDate, action, userId)
SELECT id, BudgetNumber, PositionNumber, GETDATE(), 'BEFORE UPDATE', inserted.userId
FROM MyTable
    Join inserted
        On inserted.id = MyTable.id

INSERT MyTable_History (id, BudgetNumber, PositionNumber, ModifiedDate, action, userId)
SELECT id, BudgetNumber, PositionNumber, GETDATE(), 'AFTER UPDATE', userId
FROM inserted
```

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, if you are using SQL Server 2008, there is a much better alternative than writing triggers to track data changes. Take a look at [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489.aspx).

Comment: I know this is old, but I also wanted to note that this requires Enterprise, Developer, or Evaluation editions of SQL server. This means basically you need to have Enterprise because the other two options are not legal in production.

Answer (score 0):

use `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()`

you can see further definition of what it does here
[SQL Server - current user name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101863/mssql-current-user-name/4102013#4102013)

Comment: My experience is that ORIGINAL_LOGIN is unreliable when using a proxy account. Only if users use their own personal credentials to connect to the database or if the website account impersonates the current user using Kerberos does it appear to work properly.