# Only the latest data show on table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to create table or maybe trigger that doing like this below?

```
     Date        Data

   2/6/2013         2
   2/6/2013         1
   2/6/2013         3
   2/6/2013         1
   2/6/2013         0
```

The table at top will alternately as input for next table below, but only the last input will show at table below. **The input will alternately from 2 until 0**

 Just say the input start from 2 - 1 - 3 - 1 - 0, and only 0 will show on table. 
How to make the trigger? 0 only data, not something unique. Only the latest input will show on table. Remember the table below triggered table at top to take the data.  
 I just want every time new input inserted, the data that already existed delete and only the new input will show

```
  Data
    0
```

Comment: So you want a trigger that writes history?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Table history trigger in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200407/table-history-trigger-in-sql-server)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth , i have no idea its a history or not, what I know it will give me output like that

Comment: @DanielHilgarth , I think its different. why its same?

Comment: Hey how you could possibly say my post same with the others. Why you guys just put that sign on my post. I dont see it as same post

Comment: You should read that question and the answer and understand it instead of complaining here. It is *exactly* what you want.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth . I just want every time new input inserted, the data that already existed delete and only the new input will show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want a VIEW that shows the latest value.

The following would be the query you'd use for your view...

```
SELECT TOP 1 Data FROM Table ORDER BY Date DESC
```

**EDIT** To do exactly what you want you'd just need a stored procedure for inserting.

```
-- Copy old value into history
INSERT INTO History SELECT * From Table WHERE yourCondition = True
-- Delete old value
DELETE FROM Table WHERE yourCondition = True
-- Insert new value
INSERT INTO Table VALUES(@Date, @Data)
```

Now Table will contain only 1 row with the latest value, while History will contain all the old values. This is completely non-standard and irrational, but should be exactly what you want. If you don't need history you can just remove the first INSERT statement.

Comment: no i dont want just a view table, but it will  act as real table that i can use again

Comment: @user2040175- you cannot re-create tables all the time. No one in real world would let you do this or even think of such thing. You create a view for this.

Comment: @Art , I think i dont re-create it. I just want every time new input inserted, the data that already existed delete and only the new input will show

Comment: Then I can suggest delete trigger for each row.

Comment: +1, but added some pseudo code where conditions before OP takes it too serious and deletes whole table and so on...

Comment: If the History table has no foreign keys defined, the following could replace the first two statements: `DELETE FROM Table OUTPUT DELETED.col1, DELETED.col2, ... INTO History (col1, col2, ...) WHERE condition`.