# SQL Select Statement for last entry in a dynamic table

Tags: sql, select, coldfusion, sql-order-by

I have a form that allows editing to this datatable. When certain fields are edited I need it to automatically make an entry in another database (I have that part figured out). The not must contain what the variable was before editing and what the variable has been edited to (i.e. "The user's email has been changed from something@somewhere.com to somewherer@something.com").

With the statement below, I am trying to pull information from the previous entry so I will be able to show what that variable has been changed to. The StartDate is Date/Time variable and the only variable available to pull a chronological entry.

```
SELECT Top 1 *    
FROM [Table].[dbo].[Users]
WHERE TRACK_Num = <cfqueryparam value="#form.ID#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
ORDER BY StartDate DESC
```

The main problem with this method is that it will always select the same entry instead of selecting new entries that are made through the form.

Note: I have edited the entry to include more detail. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Your query looks ok, except for the lack of query parameters.  Are you saying that you get the same track number no matter what id you submit?

Comment: Is `StartDate` a proper date/time data type?

Comment: Dan, yes but let me try to explain further. If the query executes whille the current ID is 111 and then an entry is made creating ID 112, the next time the query runs it will continue to select 111. Goat StartDate is a variable in the DB

Comment: Is the StartDate actually a datetime type, or just date? If it's just date and the entries are created on the same day I think you can get some "wrong" results. I would add ORDER BY StartDate DESC, ID DESC

Comment: Not sure why goats are part of this equation, but maybe changing the equal sign to a greater than or equal sign will help you out.  It's hard to determine what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: As an aside, it sounds like you are creating some sort of history table. If so, you might consider [other options](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200407/table-history-trigger-in-sql-server), such as a trigger, instead of the current approach. BTW, it is always good to include your dbms type in any SQL related questions.

Comment: @SinceForever please use `<cfqueryparam>` in your SQL instead of directly referencing user-input values like `#form.id#`

Comment: @Leigh the table is already created in the DB. I basically just need to pull the last entry made so that I may reference it as stated above.

Comment: @SinceForever - Yes, I understood that. My question was about your ultimate goal in plain English. If the reason you are doing this is to generate some sort of history table, there may be simpler approaches. As to why you are not getting the last entry with your current query, we need more information. While the approach is not ideal, what you described should work in theory. Though it is not thread safe.

Comment: I am sorry guys... f01 was right I meant to have the where clause based upon a different date variable. StartDate is not a date/time variable, but the one I meant to choose is however.

Comment: SinceForever - Then @f01 should post that as an answer. BTW, Stack Overflow is different than a forum. It uses a Q&A format (Question and Answer). If you overwrite your original "question", with the "answer", then ... none of the follow up comments and answers will make sense anymore ;-) So I rolled back your last edit.

Comment: Leigh - I didn't think of that, so thank you for rolling back the last edit. @f01 if you would form your comment as an answer I would gladly give you credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your field is date, and not datetime you will face problems if you have multiple entries within the same day.

Order by both StartDate DESC and ID DESC should solve this.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, then you're thinking of getting the last inserted id of the table.

```
declare @newID int 
insert into table (fields) values (values)
set @newID = scope_Identity(); // gets the latest inserted id.
select @newID
```

**Note: The ID field must have identity specification true.**

Now you can query as:

```
SELECT Top 1 *    
FROM [Table].]dbo].[Users]
WHERE TRACK_Num = @newID
ORDER BY StartDate DESC
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but I do not think it would be in relation to the new ID (the one being submitted) it would refer to the one that is most current prior to submission.