# How to move Specific row in a table to another table when that row is updated

Tags: sql-server

For example I have these two tables

```
Employee(FirstName, LastName, JoinDate, DesignationID,UpdateDate)
Employee_Designation_History(EmployeeID, DesignationID)
```

If I update employee table (changing the `DestinationID` of the `Employee`), I need to retrieve the specific data of that employee and save into the other table `Employee_Designation_History`.

Comment: What you need is a `Trigger` that recognises an update-statement on that table and automatically performs an insert in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have a column named `EmployeeId` in the first table as well.
This can be done by a [trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) fairly easy:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Employee_Update ON Employee FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    IF UPDATE(DesignationID) -- only if the relevant column changed
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Employee_Designation_History (EmployeeID, DesignationID)
    SELECT d.EmployeeID, d.DesignationID
    FROM deleted d -- That's not a typo, deleted is the correct pseudo table
    LEFT JOIN Employee_Designation_History edh 
    ON(d.EmployeeID = edh.EmployeeID 
       AND d.DesignationID = edh.DesignationID)
    WHERE edh.EmployeeID IS NULL
    END
END
```

The reason I selected the data from [deleted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) is I'm guessing you want to keep the value of DesignationID before the change. I've used LEFT JOIN on target table so if you already have a record with the same data it will not be multiplied by the trigger.
I've used the [UPDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187326.aspx) function to make sure that the column in question was indeed updated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a `Trigger` that recognises an update-statement on that table and automatically performs an insert in another table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [update_history] ON Employee 
FOR UPDATE
AS
INSERT Employee_Designation_History (EmployeeID, DesignationID)
--Use the following insert to historicize the old (overwritten) data
SELECT ??, DesignationID,
FROM Employee 
    Join inserted
        On inserted.id = Employee.id
--Use the follong insert to historicize the new (updated) data
--INSERT Employee_Designation_History (EmployeeID, DesignationID)
--SELECT  ??, DesignationID
--FROM inserted
```

Source: [Table history trigger in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200407/table-history-trigger-in-sql-server)