# Create a history trigger SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have no idea how to create this history trigger.

Imagine that we would like to store a history of price changes for each item. To do so, we would first need to create an `Item_price_history` table that stores at a minimum a reference to the item, its old price, 
its new price, and the date of the change. We could then define a trigger on the `Item` 
table that updates the `Item_price_history` table whenever an item price is updated.

I have created two tables as below:

```
CREATE TABLE ITEM(
item_id  DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
description  VARCHAR(30),
price  DECIMAL(10),
PRIMARY KEY (item_id));

CREATE TABLE Item_price_history (
history_id  DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
item_id  DECIMAL(10) NOT NULL,
old_price DECIMAL(10,2),
new_price DECIMAL(10,2),
date_of_change DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (HISTORY_ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ITEM_ID) REFERENCES item);
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200407/table-history-trigger-in-sql-server and also see this http://stackoverflow.com/help

Comment: you want trigger or anyother way to maintain Item_price_history @zichen ma

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trHistory ON dbo.ITEM 
FOR UPDATE --only for update
AS
BEGIN

    IF UPDATE(price) --if price is really updated and not the other columns
    BEGIN
       INSERT INTO dbo.Item_price_history(item_id, old_price, new_price, date_of_change)
       SELECT d.item_id, d.price, i.price, GETDATE()
       FROM Deleted d
       JOIN Inserted i ON d.item_id = i.item_id
    END           
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CREATE TRIGGER Sample ON Item_price_history
FOR UPDATE
AS
 BEGIN 

    DECLARE @nOldPRICE AS DECIMAL(10)

    SET @nOldPRICE = (SELECT price FROM DELETED)

    INSERT INTO Item_price_history (item_id, old_price, new_price, date_of_change)
    SELECT item_id, @nOldPRICE, new_price, GETDATE() FROM INSERTED

 END
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For sure you can use a trigger. But why?
You can update the history table when you update the main table and keep all the business logic in one place.

I remember in old days, during a programming SQL2000 seminar that it was told:
"Avoid the use of triggers. In most cases they try to solve design problems."

[Some info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2014/12/22/sql-server-2014-dml-triggers-tips-amp-tricks-from-the-field.aspx)

Comment: Thank you shadow, I have tried bead on other two people's answer. They both are very good.