# get domain and Computer name into updated by field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a products table i like to set machine name or domain user Name in to `[Updated By]` field whenever records are updated using trigger. I want to store domain user name into `[Updated By]`

i tried to set `[Updated By]=nt_username` but not working how can i get network informations

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATED_DATE_UPDATED_BY] 
    ON [dbo].[tableName]
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN

UPDATE T1
SET    [Updated Date] = GETDATE(),
       [Updated By]=nt_username 

FROM   TIRES T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[Auto PN] = i.[Auto PN]
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server has a built-in function to return the user name associated with the current system user.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATED_DATE_UPDATED_BY] 
    ON [dbo].[tableName]
    AFTER UPDATE
    AS 
    BEGIN
     IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
     RETURN

UPDATE T1
SET    [Updated Date] = GETDATE(),
       [Updated By]=suser_sname() 

FROM   TIRES T1
     INNER JOIN inserted i ON T1.[Auto PN] = i.[Auto PN]
END
```

More on this function here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/suser-sname-transact-sql

Comment: Thanks! but that return `sa` sqlserver username i want to show `Computer Name` or `User Name` i am using sql server express edition

Comment: Then that means sa was connected to the database or there is impersonation going on. It will show a windows ID if the domain user opened the connection and there's no impersonation happening.

Comment: Here are the other two options you can try - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4101863/sql-server-current-user-name

Comment: @mallan1121 I am not sure if i understand this very well, what do you mean by impersonation? you mean i am getting `sa` is because i have Sqlserver running on the matchine? but if i run it in the workstation/domain computer/client computers i would get the computer name or username?

Comment: @Joe, means that if you have SQL Server integrated with AD and you are added to the SQL Server users with insert/update permissions for ```tableName``` and then you updated a record in the table, the ```[Updated By]``` column would display ```YOURDOMAIN\Joe``` instead of ```sa```.

Comment: @Joe Impersonation just means you can have the trigger execute under a different user than the one who opened the connection by using the `EXECUTE AS` keywords. Based on your trigger code this isn't happening.